# Adapt dgemm example code to use sgemm (scalapack)

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, lapack, blas, scalapack

I need to make the following program (from http://www.netlib.org/scalapack/examples/pblas.tgz) work with SGEMM. What do I need to change to make it work? My knowledge of Fortran is quite limited, I'm pretty much treating this as a black-box and using it as a benchmark for my virtual cluster.

```
      PROGRAM PDPBLASDRIVER
*
*  -- PBLAS example code --
*     University of Tennessee, Knoxville, Oak Ridge National Laboratory,
*     and University of California, Berkeley.
*    
*     Written by Antoine Petitet, August 1995 (petitet@cs.utk.edu)
*
*     This program shows how to set the matrix descriptors and call
*     the PBLAS routines.
* 
*     .. Parameters ..
      INTEGER            DBLESZ, MEMSIZ, TOTMEM
      PARAMETER          ( DBLESZ = 8, TOTMEM = 400000000,
     $                     MEMSIZ = TOTMEM / DBLESZ )
      INTEGER            BLOCK_CYCLIC_2D, CSRC_, CTXT_, DLEN_, DT_,
     $                   LLD_, MB_, M_, NB_, N_, RSRC_
      PARAMETER          ( BLOCK_CYCLIC_2D = 1, DLEN_ = 9, DT_ = 1,
     $                     CTXT_ = 2, M_ = 3, N_ = 4, MB_ = 5, NB_ = 6,
     $                     RSRC_ = 7, CSRC_ = 8, LLD_ = 9 )
      DOUBLE PRECISION   ONE
      PARAMETER          ( ONE = 1.0D+0 )
*     ..
*     .. Local Scalars ..
      CHARACTER*80       OUTFILE
      INTEGER            IAM, IASEED, IBSEED, ICSEED, ICTXT, INFO, IPA,
     $                   IPB, IPC, IPW, K, KP, KQ, M, MP, MYCOL, MYROW,
     $                   N, NB, NOUT, NPCOL, NPROCS, NPROW, NQ, WORKSIZ
      DOUBLE PRECISION   BNRM2
*     ..
*     .. Local Arrays ..
      INTEGER            DESCA( DLEN_ ), DESCB( DLEN_ ), DESCC( DLEN_ )
      DOUBLE PRECISION   MEM( MEMSIZ )
*     ..
*     .. External Subroutines ..
      EXTERNAL           BLACS_EXIT, BLACS_GET, BLACS_GRIDEXIT,
     $                   BLACS_GRIDINFO, BLACS_GRIDINIT, BLACS_PINFO,
     $                   DESCINIT, IGSUM2D, PDMATGEN, PDPBLASINFO,
     $                   PDNRM2, PDGEMV, PDGEMM, PDLAPRNT
*     ..
*     .. External Functions ..
      INTEGER            NUMROC
      EXTERNAL           NUMROC
*     ..
*     .. Intrinsic Functions ..
      INTRINSIC          DBLE, MAX
*     ..
*     .. Executable Statements ..
*
*     Get starting information
*
      CALL BLACS_PINFO( IAM, NPROCS )
      CALL PDPBLASINFO( OUTFILE, NOUT, M, N, K, NB, NPROW, NPCOL, MEM,
     $                  IAM, NPROCS )
* 
*     Define process grid
*
      CALL BLACS_GET( -1, 0, ICTXT )
      CALL BLACS_GRIDINIT( ICTXT, 'Row-major', NPROW, NPCOL )
      CALL BLACS_GRIDINFO( ICTXT, NPROW, NPCOL, MYROW, MYCOL )
*
*     Go to bottom of process grid loop if this case doesn't use my
*     process
*
      IF( MYROW.GE.NPROW .OR. MYCOL.GE.NPCOL )
     $   GO TO 20
*
      MP = NUMROC( M, NB, MYROW, 0, NPROW )
      KP = NUMROC( K, NB, MYROW, 0, NPROW )
      KQ = NUMROC( K, NB, MYCOL, 0, NPCOL )
      NQ = NUMROC( N, NB, MYCOL, 0, NPCOL )
*
*     Initialize the array descriptor for the matrix A, B and C
*
      CALL DESCINIT( DESCA, M, K, NB, NB, 0, 0, ICTXT, MAX( 1, MP ),
     $               INFO )
      CALL DESCINIT( DESCB, K, N, NB, NB, 0, 0, ICTXT, MAX( 1, KP ),
     $               INFO )
      CALL DESCINIT( DESCC, M, N, NB, NB, 0, 0, ICTXT, MAX( 1, MP ),
     $               INFO )
*
*     Assign pointers into MEM for SCALAPACK arrays, A is
*     allocated starting at position MEM( 1 )
*
      IPA = 1
      IPB = IPA + DESCA( LLD_ )*KQ
      IPC = IPB + DESCB( LLD_ )*NQ
      IPW = IPC + DESCC( LLD_ )*NQ
*
      WORKSIZ = NB
*
*     Check for adequate memory for problem size
*
      INFO = 0
      IF( IPW+WORKSIZ.GT.MEMSIZ ) THEN
         IF( IAM.EQ.0 )
     $      WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9998 ) 'test', ( IPW+WORKSIZ )*DBLESZ
         INFO = 1
      END IF
*
*     Check all processes for an error
*
      CALL IGSUM2D( ICTXT, 'All', ' ', 1, 1, INFO, 1, -1, 0 )
      IF( INFO.GT.0 ) THEN
         IF( IAM.EQ.0 )
     $      WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9999 ) 'MEMORY'
         GO TO 10
      END IF
*
*     Generate random matrices A, B and C
*
      IASEED = 100
      CALL PDMATGEN( ICTXT, 'No transpose', 'No transpose', DESCA( M_ ),
     $               DESCA( N_ ), DESCA( MB_ ), DESCA( NB_ ),
     $               MEM( IPA ), DESCA( LLD_ ), DESCA( RSRC_ ),
     $               DESCA( CSRC_ ), IASEED, 0, MP, 0, KQ, MYROW, MYCOL,
     $               NPROW, NPCOL )
      IBSEED = 200
      CALL PDMATGEN( ICTXT, 'No transpose', 'No transpose', DESCB( M_ ),
     $               DESCB( N_ ), DESCB( MB_ ), DESCB( NB_ ),
     $               MEM( IPB ), DESCB( LLD_ ), DESCB( RSRC_ ),
     $               DESCB( CSRC_ ), IBSEED, 0, KP, 0, NQ, MYROW, MYCOL,
     $               NPROW, NPCOL )
      ICSEED = 300
      CALL PDMATGEN( ICTXT, 'No transpose', 'No transpose', DESCC( M_ ),
     $               DESCC( N_ ), DESCC( MB_ ), DESCC( NB_ ),
     $               MEM( IPC ), DESCC( LLD_ ), DESCC( RSRC_ ),
     $               DESCC( CSRC_ ), ICSEED, 0, MP, 0, NQ, MYROW, MYCOL,
     $               NPROW, NPCOL )

*
**********************************************************************
*     Call Level 3 PBLAS routine
**********************************************************************
*
      IF( IAM.EQ.0 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
     $         '***********************************************'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
     $         'Example of Level 3 PBLAS routine call: (PDGEMM)'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
     $         '***********************************************'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * ) ' Matrix A:'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
      END IF
*      CALL PDLAPRNT( M, K, MEM( IPA ), 1, 1, DESCA, 0, 0,
*     $               'A', NOUT, MEM( IPW ) )
*
      IF( IAM.EQ.0 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * ) ' Matrix B:'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
      END IF
*      CALL PDLAPRNT( K, N, MEM( IPB ), 1, 1, DESCB, 0, 0,
*     $               'B', NOUT, MEM( IPW ) )

      IF( IAM.EQ.0 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * ) ' Matrix C:'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
      END IF
*      CALL PDLAPRNT( M, N, MEM( IPC ), 1, 1, DESCC, 0, 0,
*     $               'C', NOUT, MEM( IPW ) )
*
      CALL PDGEMM( 'No transpose', 'No transpose', M, N, K, ONE,
     $             MEM( IPA ), 1, 1, DESCA, MEM( IPB ), 1, 1, DESCB,
     $             ONE, MEM( IPC ), 1, 1, DESCC )
*
      IF( MYROW.EQ.0 .AND. MYCOL.EQ.0 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * ) ' C := C + A * B'
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
      END IF
*      CALL PDLAPRNT( M, N, MEM( IPC ), 1, 1, DESCC, 0, 0,
*     $               'C', NOUT, MEM( IPW ) )
*
   10 CONTINUE
*
      CALL BLACS_GRIDEXIT( ICTXT )
*
   20 CONTINUE
*
*     Print ending messages and close output file
*
      IF( IAM.EQ.0 ) THEN
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = 9997 )
         WRITE( NOUT, FMT = * )
         IF( NOUT.NE.6 .AND. NOUT.NE.0 )
     $      CLOSE ( NOUT )
      END IF
*
      CALL BLACS_EXIT( 0 )
*
 9999 FORMAT( 'Bad ', A6, ' parameters: going on to next test case.' )
 9998 FORMAT( 'Unable to perform ', A, ': need TOTMEM of at least',
     $        I11 )
 9997 FORMAT( 'END OF TESTS.' )
*
      STOP
*
*     End of PDPBLASDRIVER
*
      END
```

Comment: Do you need to change pdgemm to psgemm, or pdgemm to sgemm? The first one is just conversion from double to single precision, while the second includes parallel to serial, too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scalapack library uses naming conversion to declare single or double precision function. This declaration is done by the second letter of scalapack function The "PD*" function  means a double precision function, while "PS*" means single.

So, you should change

- `DBLESZ = 8` to `DBLESZ = 4`
- All `DOUBLE PRECISION` to `REAL`
- `ONE = 1.0D+0` to `ONE = 1.0E+0`
- All `CALL PD*` to `CALL PS*`
- Perform same actions to auxiliary functions like `PDPBLASINFO`, `PDMATGEN`. `PDLAPRNT`